# Slurm: How to obtain only jobID using jobName through a script

Tags: slurm, sacct

If I know the name of a job I have run, how could I return only its jobID through a script.

For example, running `sacct --name run.sh` returns following output, where I want to return only `50` (`jobID`).

```
$ sacct --name run.sh
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
50               run.sh      debug      alper          1  COMPLETED      0:0
50.batch          batch                 alper          1  COMPLETED      0:0
```

As a solution I can run: `sacct --name run.sh | head -n3 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}'` that returns `50`, but sometimes order of `50` and `50.batch` changes for the other jobs.

Comment: I couldn't comment on how robust your strategy is. In this case though you could `grep` the output of `sacct` once more the name of your job.

Comment: If you want to do this often you could consider storing the job-id to a file from the job-script, by for example `echo "$SLURM_JOB_ID" > jobid.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following combination of options:

```
sacct -n -X --format jobid --name run.sh
```

where

- `-n` will suppress the header
- `-X` will suppress the `.batch` part
- `--format jobid` will only show the jobid column

This will output only the jobid, but if several jobs correspond to the given job name, you will get several results.